# How to convert image from double to uint8 in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image `I` which is of type `double`. I want to convert the image from `double` to `uint8`. I have tried using both:

1. `I=uint8(I)`
2. `I=im2uint8(I)`.

When I use the `imshow(I)` command, I get only a black image and nothing else. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I=im2uint8(I)` should work... What data is contained in you image? can you put an example with a 4x4 matrix that reproduces this error? Have you tried doing `imshow(I,[])`? If you rimage is double with values from 0-1, you can do `I=uint8(I*255);`

Comment: Note: It should be `im2uint8`, not `img2uint8`

Comment: @AnderBiguri sir, in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755905/how-to-superimpose-double-type-image-on-uint8-type-image-using-matlab) ,the `phase_only` image is of type `double` but i couldn't see the image by 1.converting using `im2uint8` command and 2.then `imshow(I)`

Comment: @hbaderts sir, in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755905/how-to-superimpose-double-type-image-on-uint8-type-image-using-matlab) ,the `phase_only` image is of type `double` but i couldn't see the image by 1.converting using `im2uint8` command and 2.then `imshow(I)`

Comment: We understand the problem. Thats why I asked what data is contained in your image. Make sure that your data in in the range 0-1 before the `im2uint8` call

Comment: @AnderBiguri then how to make data in the range 0-1 and see the image using `imshow(I)` command not by `imshow(I,[])` command ?

Comment: Normalization of data is a VERY SIMPLE task, I am sure you can get around a simple multiplication ;)

Comment: Try only step 2 (i.e. leave off your step )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `im2uint8` function assumes that your `double` image is scaled to the range `[0,1]`. If your image has values larger than `1` or smaller than `0`, these values will be clipped. See the following example:

```
im2uint8([-1 0 0.5 1 2])
ans =
    0    0  128  255  255
```

The solution is to scale the input image to `[0,1]` by subtracting the minimum value and dividing by the total range:

```
I = (I - min(I(:))) / (max(I(:)) - min(I(:)));
I = im2uint8(I);
imshow(I);
```

Comment: yes it's working. But why i am getting different results with your above code and `imshow(I,[])`?

Comment: `imshow(I,[])` where `I` is the original, unscaled `double` image should (and does) yield the same result as normalizing, converting to `uint8` as described in my answer. Are you sure you are calling `imshow(I,[])` on the original image?

Comment: yes sir, in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755905/how-to-superimpose-double-type-image-on-uint8-type-image-using-matlab) the `phase_only` image for your code and `imshow(I,[])` are different .

Comment: Your variable `phase_only` is complex-valued. By using `imshow(I,[])` you first discard the imaginary part and then normalize. Using my code you first normalize and then discard the imaginary part. To get the same as `imshow(I,[])` simply call `I = real(I)` first.

Comment: @devraj you may well want to plot the magnitude or phase of phase_only and not just the real part. Just something to consider.

Comment: @Dan yes ,but how to do this?

Comment: @devraj `plot(abs(I))`

Comment: I see a problem with the above transformation. If you do  I = (I - min(I(:))) / (max(I(:)) - min(I(:))), you wont be able to recover the original image.